# Evaluate limit of a functon at a point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Suppose we want to evaluate the limit of  a function $f(x) = 2x + 3$ at $2$. One way is to to find $f(2)$ and declare it to be the result. Is it a correct step to do since from the definition of limit we know that we are interested in the value when $x$ approaches close to 2 but not exactly at 2. In this sense, replacing $x$ by 2 might not be a correct step.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, then $f(\lim_{x\to x_0} x
) = f(x_0) = \lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)$.

Comment: So we can do such things when the function is continuous else not. Correct?

Comment: A function is continuous at $x_0$ **iff** the above condition holds.

Comment: Thanks. So what about the case of $\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$ when $x$ approaches 2. Is it correct to reduce to $x+2$ and then say that 4 is the limit. Why this is a correct step to do as the function is not continuous at $x=2$.

Comment: @AnirbanGhosh Because when taking the limit you only want to find values near $2$, not at $2$ itself. Notice that $\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}=x+2$ if and only if $x \ne 2$, which is fine when you just want to find the limit.

Comment: This is a good question. Technically this function is not defined at $x=2$, so continuity at $x=2$ makes no sense. However, you can extend the function to be defined at $x=2$ (since $x^2-4 = (x-2)(x+2)$) with a value that makes the extended function continuous. But, then you need to show that the resulting function is continuous, and you can't just substitute $x=2$ into the original formula.

Comment: @AnirbanGhosh How do you replace $x$ with $2$ in $\dfrac{x^2-4}{x-2}$?

Comment: @GitGud: I have never seen a definition of continuity like that. If you are talking about extending uniformly continuous functions to the closure of their domain, it makes sense, but otherwise...

Comment: @copper.hat I was confused. Disregard.

Comment: I have one remark here. By definition $f(x)$ is continuous at $x = a$ if $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = f(a)$. This means that to check continuity we should evaluate limit using some means and compare with value of function at that point. Note that if we use continuity to evaluate this limit then we are following a circular path.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider a slightly more interesting (but related) example. Let $$g(x)=\frac{2x^2-x-6}{x-2},$$ defined for all real $x\ne 2.$ It can be shown that for all $x\ne 2,$ we have $g(x)=2x-3.$ Of course, it doesn't make sense to talk about $g(2),$ since it is undefined, there. However, we can still talk about the limit as $x\to 2$. Noting that for all $x\ne 2$ we have $$|g(x)-1|=|(2x-3)-1|=|2x-4|=2|x-2|,$$ then for any $\epsilon>0$ and any $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $0<|x-2|<\frac\epsilon2,$ we have $|g(x)-1|<\epsilon,$ so $\lim_{x\to 2}g(x)=1.$

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to stick to the rules of limits.

$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}\lim_{x \to 2}f(x) &= \lim_{x \to 2}(2x + 3)\\
&= \lim_{x \to 2}2x + \lim_{x \to 2}3\\
&= 2\lim_{x \to 2}x + 3\\
&= 2\cdot 2 + 3 = 7\end{aligned}$

We have used the fact that $\lim_{x \to a}x = a$ which can be verified almost trivially using definition of a limit.

I find it totally unnecessary to invoke any higher concepts (other than definition of limits and rules of limits) to evaluate limits. Only when it is not possible to solve a problem using basic definitions and rules I go for the high level techniques like continuity, L'Hospital, series expansion, Stirling formula and what not.

We should try to stick to simple ideas to avoid confusion and learn to understand the powers of these simple rules of limits. Using these rules of limit we can show that limit of any expression consisting of algebraic, trigonometric, logarithmic, exponential functions when $x \to a$ can be evaluated by a direct substitution of $x = a$ in the expression provided that such a substitution does not lead to any undefined expression (like zero in denominator, log of zero etc.)